# Entering Text into UISearchBar button calabash iOS testing

Tags: cucumber, calabash

I am having a bit of trouble getting my_first_steps.rb to proceed further than the initial load test "Given I am on the Welcome Screen".
I have sought in depth examples of inputting text into the UISearchBarTextField and have unfortunately fell short of my intended goal of creating a functional test. I am not completely fluent with ruby (or Gherkin, given that the reference site is incomplete) if someone would care to share enlightenment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The .feature and .rb files are as follows

my_first.feature:

```
Feature: Running a test
  As an iOS developer
  I want to have a sample feature file
  So I can begin testing quickly

Scenario: Example steps
  Given I am on the Welcome Screen
  Then I touch “searchBar” button
  Then I enter "Fire Tower" into the "searchBar" input field
```

my_first_steps.rb:

```
Given /^I am on the Welcome Screen$/ do
 element_exists("view")
 sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end

Then /^I touch "searchBar" button$/ do
 touch("view marked:searchBar")
end

Then /^I enter "Fire Tower" into the UISearchBarTextField$/ do
 sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you pasted the output you get, but I do think I can help you.
1. Try using the calabash console to try out the calls you want to put into your steps. See how here https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/01-Getting-started-guide
2. In this step

```
touch("view marked:searchBar")
```

you are forgetting single quotes around the mark. It should be

```
touch("view marked:'searchBar'")
```

However from earlier experience I had some problems touching a searchbar and my solution back then was to do a touch based on the help text that was displayed in the searchbar. So if you have problems getting this to work you can try that approach.

Comment: I have applied the following fix and am receiving:

Comment: 1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (1 skipped, 1 undefined, 1 passed)
0m9.522s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Then(/^I touch “searchBar” button$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Answer (score 0):

It is a smart-quotes problem. Your editor has changed from double-quotes to some other unicode character.

`Then I touch “searchBar” button`

Should be

`Then I touch "searchBar" button`

in your step definition. I suggest using a text-editor better suited for programming, or disabling smart-quotes.